# Javascript method for getting data based on ID in database table

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, database, methods

I'm building an app with many different datasets. Locations, customers, ratings etc...

Throughout the app there are popups and dynamically filled modules, dropdowns etc... At the moment my method is to attach "data-id" as an attribute to any buttons that create dynamic content then run ajax functions using the attribute to get content for the popup.

I'm assuming this is the correct thing to do for large modules that require a lot of dynamic data, but take the below example.

I have a list of locations, when the user clicks (add link) I'd like the popup module to have the title 'Adding link to [location name]'. Would I really need to create an ajax function simply to fill in the name of the location from the database? I could get it from the DOM but that seems silly because most of the popups require data that isn't in the dom.

Basically, my question is; **What is the easiest way to get basic data from the database in javascript?**

Here's an example of what I have for a whole bunch of buttons with various modules and titles:

```
$('body').on('click','.add_board_to_loc',function(){
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

let getLocation = function(id){
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'includes/ajax.php',
  data: {
    action: 'getLocation',
    loc_id: id
  },
  success: function(data){
    $('#add_link_modal_title').text(data['location_name']);
  }
  });
  }
  $('#addBoardModal').modal('show');
  });
```

Comment: any minimal version of what you need and what you already have ?

Comment: @simondehaut sure thing. I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I would split this code into several layers.

One layer can be a transport layer. On transport layer you make ajax request and process errors.

The next layer can be a general layer, here you pass params as table, where statmets and so on. Anyone will be able to access this data through api so be carful with permissions.

And the last layer can be Buisness layer where you request things like: get Location.